# CASE inside IF() function in raw SQL query

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails-5

I have a SQL query which already uses an IF() function to check some conditions on basis of which respective expression is returned. I have to add another condition (which will be another 'and') inside the IF() which will affect the attributes from both the expressions. The query is,

```
select 
  #{booking_variable}.travel_id as operator_id,
  round(sum(#{ticket_variable}.customer_commission), 2) as commission,
  IF(
    (#{booking_variable}.is_online = #{AdminType::YES} 
      and #{booking_variable}.is_ts_payment = #{AdminType::YES}),
    round(sum(-#{ticket_variable}.customer_commission
      - #{ticket_variable}.convenience_charge_amount
      + #{ticket_variable}.our_convenience_charge_amount), 2),
    round(sum(#{ticket_variable}.adult_fare 
      - #{ticket_variable}.customer_commission
      + #{ticket_variable}.service_tax_amount
      + #{ticket_variable}.our_convenience_charge_amount 
      - #{ticket_variable}.offer_discount), 2)
  ) as amount_to_be_paid,
  round(sum(#{booking_variable}.total_fare)) as total_fare,
  0 as cancel_fare,
  round(sum(#{ticket_variable}.adult_fare 
      + #{ticket_variable}.service_tax_amount
      - #{ticket_variable}.offer_discount )) as net_amount,
  #{booking_variable}.travel_name as operator_name,
  ROUND(sum(#{ticket_variable}.service_tax_amount), 2) as total_service_tax,
  ROUND(sum(#{ticket_variable}.convenience_charge_amount), 2) as total_convenience_charge_amount,
  ROUND(sum(#{ticket_variable}.our_convenience_charge_amount), 2) as total_our_convenience_charge_amount,
  0 as cancelled_convenience_charge_amount,
  (select users.branch_id from users where id=#{ticket_variable}.booked_by) as travel_branch_id
from #{booking_variable} use index(index_#{booking_variable}_travel_date), 
  #{ticket_variable}
where #{conditions1[0]} 
group by travel_branch_id, operator_id
```

Here, inside the IF() expression, I have to check another variable's value . If the value is true, then the query should run as is, if not, the value of `#{ticket_variable}.convenience_charge_amount + #{ticket_variable}.our_convenience_charge_amount` and `#{ticket_variable}.our_convenience_charge_amount` is to be taken as 0. 
Any help appreciated.

Comment: Please reformat your query so we can read it.

Comment: Thank you @bill for editing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can nest `IF()` expressions.

If you need part of your calculation to be conditional, you can use an `IF()` for that.

```
...
  IF(
    (#{booking_variable}.is_online = #{AdminType::YES} 
      and #{booking_variable}.is_ts_payment = #{AdminType::YES}),
    round(sum(-#{ticket_variable}.customer_commission
      - IF((...some other condition...),
        #{ticket_variable}.convenience_charge_amount
        + #{ticket_variable}.our_convenience_charge_amount,
        0)
      ), 2),
...
```

Comment: I ended up putting the condition in a variable outside and substituting them as per ternary IF conditional in rails. Thanks for the SQL level solution @Bill